# Why does it get slow when I use navigation component "navigation graph" with bottom navigation bar? Should I use Fragment Transaction instead

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation

when I go to home fragment it lags a little but when I go to any other fragment "which are empty" it doesn't lag

[image: Main Activity]

Home Fragment "The Only slow fragment"

> package com.example.ecom.ui.home
>
> import android.os.Bundle
> import android.view.LayoutInflater
> import android.view.View
> import android.view.ViewGroup
> import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
> import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
> import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
> import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
> import com.example.ecom.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding
>
> class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
>
> private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
>
> This property is only valid between onCreateView and
> onDestroyView.
> private val binding get() = _binding!!
>
> override fun onCreateView(
> inflater: LayoutInflater,
> container: ViewGroup?,
> savedInstanceState: Bundle?
> View {
> val homeViewModel =
> ViewModelProvider(this)[HomeViewModel::class.java]
>
> _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
>
> binding.viewModel = homeViewModel
>
> binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
>
> val popularProductsAdapter = PopularProductsAdapter()
>
> val allProductAdapter = PopularProductsAdapter()
>
> val categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter()
>
> binding.saleProductsRecycler.adapter = allProductAdapter
>
> binding.popularProductsRecycler.adapter = popularProductsAdapter
>
> binding.categoryRecycler.adapter = categoryAdapter
>
> categoryAdapter.selectedCategory = {
> homeViewModel.getProductsFromRemote(it)
> }
>
> homeViewModel.categories.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
> categoryAdapter.submitList(it)
> })
>
> allProductAdapter.selectedProduct = {
> homeViewModel.displayProductDetails(it)
> }
>
> popularProductsAdapter.selectedProduct = {
> homeViewModel.displayProductDetails(it)
> }
>
> homeViewModel.navigateSelectedProduct.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
> if (it!=null) {
> this.findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionNavigationHomeToProductDetailsFragment(it))
> homeViewModel.displayProductDetailsComplete()
> }
> })
>
> return binding.root
> }
>
> override fun onDestroyView() {
> super.onDestroyView()
> _binding = null
> }
> }

Home View Model

> package com.example.ecom.ui.home
>
> import android.util.Log
> import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
> import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
> import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
> import com.example.ecom.network.ApiService
> import com.example.ecom.network.Product
> import kotlinx.coroutines.*
>
> class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
>
> private val _products = MutableLiveData<List>()
> val products: LiveData<List> get() = _products
>
> private val _popularProducts = MutableLiveData<List>()
> val popularProducts: LiveData<List> get() = _popularProducts
>
> private val _categories = MutableLiveData<List>()
> val categories: LiveData<List> get() = _categories
>
> private val _status = MutableLiveData()
> val status: LiveData get() = _status
>
> private val _navigateSelectedProduct = MutableLiveData<Product?>()
> val navigateSelectedProduct: LiveData<Product?> get() = _navigateSelectedProduct
>
> private val job = Job()
>
> private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.Main)
>
> init {
> getCategoryFromRemote()
> getProductsFromRemote("All")
> }
>
> private fun getCategoryFromRemote() {
> coroutineScope.launch {
> val getCategoriesDeferred = ApiService.retrofitService.getCategoriesAsync()
> try {
> val listResult = getCategoriesDeferred.await()
> if(listResult.isNotEmpty()) {
> val list = mutableListOf()
> list.add("All")
> list.addAll(listResult)
> _categories.value = list
> }
> catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
> _status.value = "Failure: ${e.message}"
> }
> }
> }
>
> fun getProductsFromRemote(string: String) {
> coroutineScope.launch {
> var getProductsDeferred: Deferred<List>? = null
> getProductsDeferred = if (string == "All") {
> ApiService.retrofitService.getProductsAsync()
> else {
> ApiService.retrofitService.getProductsOfCategoryAsync(string)
> }
> try {
> val listResult = getProductsDeferred.await()
> Log.i("problem", listResult.toString())
> if (listResult.isNotEmpty()) {
> _products.value = listResult
> val popularProductsList = mutableListOf()
> for (i in listResult) {
> if (i.rating.rate >= 4.0) {
> popularProductsList.add(i)
> }
> }
> _popularProducts.value = popularProductsList
>
> ```
>             }
> ```
>
> catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
> _status.value = "Failure: ${e.message}"
> }
> }
> }
>
> fun displayProductDetails(product: Product) {
> _navigateSelectedProduct.value = product
> }
>
> fun displayProductDetailsComplete() {
> _navigateSelectedProduct.value = null
> }
>
> override fun onCleared() {
> super.onCleared()
> job.cancel()
> }
>
> }

Navigation bar system trace
[image: Navigation bar system trace]

I think this is the trace of what happens when I click on the home fragment in the nav bar
[image: I think this is the trace of what happens when I click on the home fragment in the nav bar]
More details trace
[image]

I tried to use Fragment Transaction and it was so quick and smooth. but I don't know how can I use it with nav graph. because to use navigation component I have to remove those lines ->

> app:defaultNavHost="true"
> app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"

and the application will crash if I did so and used the nav graph to navigate.

so What should i do? any advice on that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All the Navigation Component is doing is the same kind of FragmentTransaction (and it is also saving your state so that your ViewModel doesn't even need to do its query again). What does a [trace](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/tracing) say is actually slow?

Comment: I added an image for the nav bar system trace. But I don't really understand it as it's my first to use sys trace. what should I do next ?

Comment: Are your problem fixed?